# How to change .net chart width to %100

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, width, resolution

How can I set the width of an asp:chart to be 100% the width of the page?
The chart width attribute does not like percentages.

Another solution would be to check the current resolution, how to get that from .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.screenpixelswidth.aspx) property.